# Copy SQL data from one server to another using c# threading

Tags: c#, sql-server, multithreading

I am new to Threading in c#, hence asking this question. Please correct me if i am wrong anywhere in my below question, it might be because of lacking of knowledge in C# threading.

I have an array (type of string) that contains all the Table Names (of SQL server), now I want to read data of these tables using sql query and write to another server. i can do it using synchronous programming, but this will take time. Can we do it using async/await or ThreadPool or Threading.

I want 4 (or 5) threads that can run parallaly and read the string array, collect table name and read the table data from sql server, post these activities this thread should create the table in my local server and write the data.

Comment: Use your existing code (you do have some right?  Your question says are only new to Threading in c#), and then use Parallel.ForEach over the array.

Comment: `Parallel.ForEach` with a `ParallelOptions.MaxDegreeOfParallelism` set to 4 or 5? However: this isn't a magic wand, and using 4 or 5 threads does not mean it will *necessarily* take 1/4 or 1/5 of the time - network bandwidth, IO bandwidth, and client and server CPU can all be bottlenecks. You'd also probably want to ensure you're using tools like `SqlBulkCopy`. But frankly, this sounds like something an off-the-shelf tool (or the inbuilt RDBMS tools) should be doing...

Comment: Can you show us your existing code?

Comment: Why not use replication of SQL Server?

Answer (score 0):

Oracle has something called database link. Probably SQL server has something similar too. I would recommend creating a db link. Then you can select the data from the source server to target server just using sql query without loading it into your C# code. Meanwhile, you can use your app for submitting the queries to the db. You can do it concurrently, one query per thread and all the threads are doing is submitting the query and waiting for its completion.